# How to generate dynamic property getter/setter?

Tags: objective-c

I want to add a property implementation method at runtime. Add I use +resolveInstanceMethod, class_addMethod to do. But below the code, in dynamicN() and dynamicSetN(), they can't be compiled and I don't know how to use C-Function to set/get instance variable without synthesize property.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

float dynamicN(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    NSString *methodName = NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);
    NSLog(@"%@,%@", methodName, [self description]);
    // return [self n];
}

void dynamicSetN(id self, SEL _cmd, float sname)
{
    printf("setName start;\n");
    // self.n = sname;   
}


@interface bird : NSObject
{
    int height;
    float n;
}

@property float n;
@property int height;

@end

@implementation bird
@synthesize height = height;
@dynamic n;

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        n = 1.0;
        height = 3;
    }
    return self;
}

- (float) n {
    return n;
}

+ (BOOL) resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)aSEL
{
    if (aSEL == @selector(n)) {
        //class_addMethod([self class], aSEL, (IMP) dynamicN, "f@:");
        //return YES;
    }
    if (aSEL == @selector(setN:)) {
        class_addMethod([self class], aSEL, (IMP) dynamicSetN, "v@:f");
        return YES;
    }
    return [super resolveInstanceMethod:aSEL];
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    bird *aBird = [[bird alloc] init];
    aBird.n = 3;
    printf("\n%f\n,%d", aBird.n, aBird.height);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the error messages you're getting from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@H2CO3 is correct about your setter. The dynamic getter has the same basic problem. You're trying to call `[self n]`, which doesn't exist on `id`. <strike>That's why it won't compile.</strike> (As @H2CO3 notes, this will generate a warning, not an error; you're all using `-Werror`, right?) But more importantly, even if it did, this would be an infinite loop. `self.n` is just a call to `[self n]`, which will dispatch back to this function.

If you are looking for examples, you can download the code for chapter 20 of [iOS 6 Programming Pushing the Limits](https://github.com/iosptl/ios6ptl/tree/master/ch28/Person/Person). Look in the `Person` project for `Person.m`. Chapter 28 includes a lot more explanation on how to implement this kind of feature if you're interested.

Note that proper naming in ObjC is very important. Your class should be `Bird`, not `bird`. Getting naming basics under your belt is critical before attempting advanced features like dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

Your setter won't compile because your `self` parameter is of type "id" which in itself has no property named "n". You'll want to cast then direct dereference it:

```
((bird *)self)->n = sname;
```

Your getter seems good though, I don't know why it can't be compiled.

Comment: The getter calls itself and wouldn't work at runtime. The same field access as for the setter needs to be made to get the return value there. I can't see why it wouldn't compile either, though.

Comment: Type "id" syntactically don't have a property named "n". The compiler doesn't know it actually responds to the -n or -setN: methods (that's the price of dynamism)

Comment: Whether it means that the use of (id)-dynamic type bind is different from static type in C-Function? Is there some differences between static type and dynamic type in objective-c method?